# DeadObjectException When Dealing With Singleton - Android

Tags: android, singleton

My application is a painting application that allows the user to paint on a canvas using multiple different brush colors. The application saves the paintings across multiple runs of the application so that when the program loads, the user can cycle through the different paintings using 'previous' and 'next' buttons. My application saves paintings as instances of my custom PaintingModel class, which represents a single painting, which in turn stores a list of [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) objects.

```
public class PaintingModel {
private List<Path> strokes;

public PaintingModel() {
    strokes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addStroke(Path stroke) {
    strokes.add(stroke);
}

public List<Path> getStrokes() {
    return strokes;
}
```

The way in which I save my paintings is as a collection of PaintingModel objects, i.e. List.

A singleton, which I use as a way to access global application state, contains code that saves my list of paintings, and loads them from save file on new application sessions. I have debugged the saving and reading from the file and feel fairly certain that this is working properly. Here is my singleton class:

```
public class Gallery {
private static Gallery gallery = null;
// context is required to access file writing/reading methods under Context class
private Context context = null;
// holds all saved paintings
private List<PaintingModel> paintings = new ArrayList<>();
// references the currently visible painting
private PaintingModel currentPainting; // represents the current currentPainting
// convert painting objects into serializable form
private Gson serializer = new Gson();
// references the object in memory that represents the saved painting information
private File saveFile;
// index of current painting
public int paintingIndex;
// name of saved painting file
private final String FILENAME = "gallery_save_file";
// currently selected splotch color
private int currentColor = Color.BLACK;

private Gallery(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    saveFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    paintingIndex = 0;
    currentPainting = new PaintingModel();
    paintings = readPaintingsFromFile();
    paintings.add(currentPainting);
}

public static Gallery getInstance(Context _context) {
    if (gallery == null)
        gallery = new Gallery(_context);
    return gallery;
}

public void newStroke(Path stroke) {
    currentPainting.addStroke(stroke);
    savePainting();
}

private void savePainting() {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PaintingModel>>() {}.getType();
        String serializedPaintings = serializer.toJson(paintings, listType);
        fos.write(serializedPaintings.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Read from the saved file to load all user-saved paintings
 * @return List data containing saved paintings from previous sessions
 */
public List<PaintingModel> readPaintingsFromFile() {
    FileInputStream fis;
    byte[] obs = new byte[(int) saveFile.length()]; // add enough space for n newlines
    try {
        if (saveFile.exists()) {
            fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
            int bytesRead = fis.read(obs);
            if (bytesRead <= 0)
                Log.i("TAG", "read 0 bytes from save file");
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "file not found");
    }
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PaintingModel>>() {}.getType();
    String deserializedData = new String(obs);
    List<PaintingModel> results = serializer.fromJson(deserializedData, listType);
    return (results == null) ? new ArrayList<PaintingModel>() : results;
}

public boolean deleteSaveFile() {
    return saveFile.delete();
}

public List<PaintingModel> getPaintings() {
    return paintings;
}

public PaintingModel getPainting() {
    return currentPainting;
}

public int getColor() {
    return currentColor;
}

public void setCurrentColor(int color) {
    currentColor = color;
}
```

The idea is that when the singleton 'Gallery' is created, it loads all the previously saved paintings into 'List paintings' from the save file which is later accessed when I need to cycle through paintings in the drawing canvas view. Herein lies the problem - when I attempt to redraw a previous or next painting by accessing its list of Path objects, the app crashes and my Run console outputs a [DeadObjectException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html), indicating that host process is gone.

In my view class, which shows the current drawable canvas, and where I attempt to draw next/previous paintings, I have the method:

```
public void showNextPainting() {
    drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    List<PaintingModel> paintings = Gallery.getInstance(getContext()).getPaintings();
    PaintingModel nextPainting = paintings.get(Gallery.getInstance(getContext()).paintingIndex);
    drawCanvas.drawPath(new Path(nextPainting.getStrokes().get(0)), drawPaint);
    invalidate();
}
```

which I use to first wipe the canvas, then retrieve the next painting in my list of paintings held by the singleton. Here, I am simply grabbing the first painting in my list as an initial test. No matter which painting object, the application always crashes when I try to draw a single Path within a PaintingModel instance. This code works fine when I draw a newly instantiated Path object with a simple shape attached like a rectangle.

Full Stack trace

[image: stack trace 1]

[image: stack trace pt 2]

[image: stack trace pt 3]

Comment: can you also post the stacktrace?

Comment: @ginomempin added.